# How can i use blob storage from an azure function in Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I have an http triggered azure function (written in Java) in which I want to access Blob storage. The code compiles under maven, but when I run it locally and send a post from CURL, the runtime crashes due to a ClassNotFound exception caused by missing com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount. azure-storage (version 6.0.0) is listed as a dependency in the POM file. Where should the related .jar files be so that they are seen by the function?

Any insights regarding Java azure functions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your needs,I suggest you following this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven) to create,run and deploy your `java azure function`.

***Function Class:***

```
package com.fabrikam.functions;

import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.ExecutionContext;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*;

/**
 * Hello function with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {

    // Configure the connection-string with your values
    public static final String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
                    "AccountName=***;" +
                    "AccountKey=***";

    @FunctionName("hello")
    public String hello(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {"get", "post"}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) String req,
                        ExecutionContext context) {

        try {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

            // Get a reference to a container.
            // The container name must be lower case
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(req);

            // Create the container if it does not exist.
            container.createIfNotExists();

            return String.format("Hello, I get container name : %s!", container.getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Access Error!";
        }
    }
}
```

***Pom.xml：***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fabrikam.functions</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabrikam-functions</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <functionAppName>fabrikam-functions-20171017112209094</functionAppName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1.4</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <region>westus2</region>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>beta</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>host.json</include>
                                        <include>local.settings.json</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Then use command `mvn clean package` to pack your maven project into a jar package.

[image]

use command `mvn azure-functions:run` to run your azure function locally.

[image]

---

***Update Answer:***

I ran my azure function and reproduce the same exception as you said.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount

```
Exception:
Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at com.microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:19)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at com.microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:34)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at com.microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:40)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at com.microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at com.microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at com.microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:41)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at com.microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:84)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at com.fabrikam.functions.Function.hello(Function.java:26)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         ... 16 more
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]         ... 17 more
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM] .
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM]   Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is '3450abda-99a0-4d75-add2-a7bc48a0cb51'
[10/25/2017 2:48:44 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.hello. System.Private.CoreLib: Result:
```

After some research, I found out that it was because the jar packaged without  `dependent jar packages`.

So , I added the snippet of configuration as below into my `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Your main class path</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Then please use command `mvn-clean-package` and you will see two jar files generated.

[image]

One is that it does not contain `dependent jar packages`, and the second one contains `dependent jar packages`.

Move the `fabrikam-functions-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies` jar into the path：`${project.basedir}/target/azure-functions/${function-app-name}/`

For me ,it looks like `E:\TestAzureFunction\fabrikam-functions\target\azure-functions\fabrikam-functions-20171017112209094`.

Don't forget rename the jar to `fabrikam-functions-1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Finally, I run the azure function successfully and get the output result via the url: `http://localhost:7071/api/mongo`.

[image]

In addition, you could refer to this [github doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/master/azure-functions-maven-plugin#configuration) for more configuration details about azure `function maven plugin`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think you will find that if you actually execute your function (what is shown above simply indicates the function is loaded), it will crash with the same error that I encountered. Use CURL to send an HTTP message to it. If it does not crash, then please tell me where the MS storage libraries are located on your local machine.

Comment: I am curious if you were able to run your function using CURL. I was able to create and run locally a C# function that looks pretty much like your Java code and works as expected using Azure C# libraries (though I had to manually add an assembly to Visual Studio). This makes me think the problem I encountered is in fact due to some idiosyncrasy of my Maven environment, and I don't know Maven well. I would like to use a Java function because I have other Java code I don't want to convert to C#. So if you were successful, please let me know.

Comment: @JackCopper Sorry to reply you so late, please give me some time to update my answer.Thanks.

Comment: @JackCopper Please see my update answer. I met the same issue and figured it out.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have been sidetracked but will try to implement your solution today.

Comment: Your solution, along with the updated POM description from MS in the link you provided, works. The original POM file created by MS when I first downloaded the example had the "azure-functions-maven-plugin" in the wrong place (according to the latest POM), and was using 0.1.5. Microsoft @JeffHollan should hire you as a consultant to vet all the Maven POM files

Answer (score 0):

Can you share any details on the method and types you are using?  To do output bindings you need to use the `OutputBinding<T>` class with the correct annotation.  Here's an example of one I just tested to do similar to what you mentioned:

```
@FunctionName("hello")
public String hello(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {
                "post" }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) String req,
        ExecutionContext context, @BlobOutput(name = "blob", connection = "StorageAccount", path = "test/foo.txt")OutputBinding<String> blob)
        {
    blob.setValue("hello world");
    return String.format("Hello, %s!", req);
}
```

Notice the @BlobOutput attribute and the OutputBinding type (could be `String` or `byte []`, but I believe if doing `byte []` you also need to set the dataType to "binary" on the @BlobAttribute.

Let me know if that works

Comment: The use case is: a container ID and a specific file name are in the request header; the blob is an arbitrary file (text) in a fixed location in the hierarchy of any container that is passed in; in the function I need to read a few lines then add meta-data to the blob. Your answer has pointed me to looking at other annotations (e.g., I think in need to use stream) but I am still struggling with the basics of getting parameters from request header to the blob name and connection parameters required.